# Why can't I use the NCHAR function on an EXEC statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why can't I do this?

```
EXEC mySproc NCHAR(0xA5)
```

I get

> Incorrect syntax near '0xa5'.

yet, I can do this

```
DECLARE @foo NCHAR
SET @foo = NCHAR(0xA5)
EXEC mySproc @foo
```

and even this

```
SELECT NCHAR(0xA5)
```

It is interesting how SQL server chooses to evaluate expressions. Any thoughts?

Comment: why the -1? i would appreciate knowing why.

Comment: [See this related connect item request](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/352110/t-sql-use-scalar-functions-as-stored-procedure-parameters). The answer to "Why?" seems to be that they just haven't got round to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it violates an T-SQL [stored procedure call syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188332.aspx) which states:

```
Execute a stored procedure or function
[ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]
    { 
      [ @return_status = ]
      { module_name [ ;number ] | @module_name_var } 
        [ [ @parameter = ] { value 
                           | @variable [ OUTPUT ] 
                           | [ DEFAULT ] 
                           }
        ]
      [ ,...n ]
      [ WITH RECOMPILE ]
    }
[;]
```

where **value**

> Is the value of the parameter to pass to the module or pass-through
>   command. If parameter names are not specified, parameter values must
>   be supplied in the order defined in the module.
>
> When executing pass-through commands against linked servers, the order
>   of the parameter values depends on the OLE DB provider of the linked
>   server. Most OLE DB providers bind values to parameters from left to
>   right.
>
> If the value of a parameter is an object name, character string, or
>   qualified by a database name or schema name, the whole name must be
>   enclosed in single quotation marks. If the value of a parameter is a
>   keyword, the keyword must be enclosed in double quotation marks.
>
> If a default is defined in the module, a user can execute the module
>   without specifying a parameter.
>
> The default can also be NULL. Generally, the module definition
>   specifies the action that should be taken if a parameter value is
>   NULL.

**thus**

you should first perform all the calculations, place the results into variables and then pass the variables into SP call

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass function calls as arguments into a stored procedure.  You have to evaluate them first (as you did in your second example), and then pass them in.

You can see that this will also fail:

```
exec myProc len('abc')
```

Comment: Its how EXECUTE behaves, `execute('select ' + NCHAR(0xA5))` would fail also

Comment: It seems rather unfortunate to me too.  There have been any number of times it would just be a lot simpler, but that's the way it is.  Oleg has a good answer as to the why.